# How can I get file size and modified date on the V3 Google Drive API?

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I'm upgrading from v2 to v3 of the Google Drive API on Android and would like to know how to get some extra fields when I query for files, ideally without paging.

This is the code I got:

```
FileList result = drive.files().list()
                .setQ("'root' in parents  and trashed=false")
                .setFields("files(id, name, fileSize, modifiedDate, mimeType)")
                .execute();
```

But it says that `invalid field selection fileSize`.

Also I would like a way to get a download url for the file that works temporarily for sharing with other apps. This used to be achievable with `getDownloadUrl` and adding the token on v2.

Thanks.

Edit: Looks like the correct fields are:

```
            .setFields("files(id, name, size, modifiedTime)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently `files(size)` works although I don't see it documented. You can try it [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list#parameters).

I am not so sure about `getDownloadUrl`. You can check the v2 to v3 conversion documentation at [this page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration). It suggests that `files.get with ?alt=media` might be a suitable replacement for `downloadUrl`.

Comment: How do I add that `alt=media` stuff? I'm doing `drive.files().get(id).execute()` ?

Comment: @casolorz Take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#using_altmedia).

Comment: Thanks, `size` is correct and I guess it is `modifiedTime` not what I had. I was looking at the middle column. I'll mark this as correct, the download address worked as well.

Answer (score 1):

When you get files from a folder:

```
val files = driveService.files().list()
                    .setSpaces("appDataFolder")
                    .setFields("files(id, name, createdTime)")
                    .execute()
```

When you create file:

```
val file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
                    .setFields("id, name, createdTime")
                    .execute()
```

You can see  all available properties [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#properties).

Answer (score 0):

modifiedDate did not work for me, although it says on the documents. modifiedTime gives both date and time

```
$params = array
(
  'pageSize' => 1000,
  'fields' => "nextPageToken, files(id , name , modifiedTime)",
  'q' => "'" . $parent_folder_id . "' in parents"
) ;
$files = $service -> files -> listFiles($params) ;   
foreach ($files as $file)
{
  echo($file -> getModifiedTime()) ;
  echo($file -> getName()) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*` to get the all fields of a file.

```kotlin
val files = drive.files().list().setSpaces("appDataFolder")
                .setFields("nextPageToken, files(*)")
                .setPageSize(10)
                .execute()
```